# How can I run my own scripts in kate 3.8.2? "External tools" isn't available in the plugins section

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, kate, plugin

I am using Kubuntu 12.04 LTS. How can I run my own scripts in `kate` 3.8.2?

It appears that the plugin named *External tools* is no longer available.

I would like to run Python or shell scripts in kate and invoke them using a keyboard shortcut, such as <kbd>F4</kbd>.

As an example, this simple script would ideally change to a specific window when I press <kbd>F4</kbd>.

```
#!\bin\sh
wmctrl -a "<Window name>"
```

Comment: [Apparently, there's no maintainer...](http://kate-editor.org/2011/08/09/maintainer-needed-kate-external-tools-plugin/)

Comment: @sr_ This is a very very sad thing to me. You're right, no maintainer. So I will need a simillar editor with a tool like that. I tried gedit and works, but the editor itself have very few options.

Comment: [There're lots of them... `;)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) For scriptability, you could always give (g)VIM or EMACS a try, but there's also [textadept](http://foicica.com/textadept/), for example...

Comment: How to end this question? There's no maintainer, so, would I embrace a answer telling this? If yes, please sr_, write a answer to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Unfortunately, there currently is no maintainer for this plugin.](http://kate-editor.org/2011/08/09/maintainer-needed-kate-external-tools-plugin/)

However, there [are lots of popular editors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_text_editors) that support this one way or another. Apart from the usual suspects ((g)VIM, EMACS) [SciTE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SciTE) has pretty good support for external scripts, I'd say.

And there's [Acme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acme_%28text_editor%29), quite uniquely integrated with scripting, pipe redirections etc, lacking syntax coloring and the like you'd probably expect from a modern editor.

Answer (score 2):

In `KATE 3.8.5` there is `Build Plugin`. It will add Build menu and Build configuration (look at the bottom left, next to Terminal). If you open build configuration there is tab `Target Settings` and you can set commands in 'Build', 'Clean' and 'Quick compile'. You can configure and short key for these commands.

P.S. This is only work around if you have up to 3 different scripts/commands you need to execute